# Can't pull the splash image from docker

Tags: docker, web-scraping, scrapy-splash

I tried to download the image of the splash using the docker command like shown below, but it was failing with error "Tag latest not found in repository scrapinghub/splash"

sudo docker pull scrapinghub/splash

I tried to pull the image by getting the latest tag name from the docker website "https://hub.docker.com/r/scrapinghub/splash/tags/" as below, but even this ended with the same error.

sudo docker pull scrapinghub/splash:2.3.2

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 version. On the other hand can I download the image from "https://hub.docker.com/r/scrapinghub/splash/" there are some URL's in the repository details page are these the same as the image that I am trying to pull?

Comment: I'd suggest just trying again. Works here.

Comment: Hi Adrian, Can you please tell me which script did you use to pull the splash. Means did you specify the version at the end of the pull?

Comment: I did `docker pull scrapinghub/splash` which is equivalent to `docker pull scrapinghub/splash:latest`

Comment: Hi, I have resolved this issue by upgrading the version of ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.

Now the Docker is able to pull the image. Thanks Adrian and all for your support.

Comment: Ok. Glad it works.